# Declarate and using map in structs

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, type-declaration, golang-migrate

I'am so very noob in golang and started only a fews days ago.

Actually I'm trying make a simple exercise for get used to the golang syntax.

I have this in main.go:

```
package main 

import(
    "fmt"
    // "stringa"
    "main/survey"
)

func main() {
    var questions = []survey.Question{
        {
            Label: "Questão 1",
            Instructions : "Instrução",
            Options : {
                1 : "Op1",
                2 : "Op2",
            },
            Answer: {
                1 : "Op1",
            },
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(questions[0].Label)
}
```

And I try make a simple structures, but i know. that problems is solveld if I use an interface, but if in next steps I will need using maps in structure...

PS: this is a sample struct I have used:

```
package survey

import(
    // "fmt"
    // "strings"
    // "strconv"
)

// This is a simple Question in a survey code
type Question struct {
    // This is a label for the quetsion
    Label string
    // This is a instructions and is not required
    Instructions string
    // this is a multiple options answer
    Options map[int]string
    // this is a answer correct response
    Answer map[int]string
}
```

Finally the question is:

**How can I use map in parameters from inside the struct and write this in the declaration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type (`map[int]string`) must be used in a composite literal expression for a struct field value:

```
var questions = []survey.Question{
    {
        Label:        "Questão 1",
        Instructions: "Instrução",
        Options: map[int]string{
            1: "Op1",
            2: "Op2",
        },
        Answer: map[int]string{
            1: "Op1",
        },
    },
}
```

The type in a composite literal expression can only be elided on slice elements (as it is with the elements of the `[]survey.Question`), map keys and map values.

[Run it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hCSXDY9d1ps).